# Transform a input json to { "Name": ["John Doe"], "Email": ["John_Doe@User.opa.com"],"Address": ["123 Willow Dr, San Jose, CA"]}

Tags: opa, rego

How Do i transform this line from  `{ "Name": ["John Doe"], "Email": ["John_Doe@User.opa.com"],"Address": ["123 Willow Dr, San Jose, CA"]}` to this

```
 { "Name": ["John Doe"], "Email": ["John_Doe"],"Address": ["123 Willow Dr, San Jose, CA"]}.
```

Replace the domain name with spaces if exists. The input json may or may not have @User.opa.com.

I tried to apply reg_ex match, I dont think I am getting the right results.